# In one word, how can I say that something can be scored?

Tags: word-request, translation

In my native language, there's a single word that identifies an object as something that can get a score, let's say, from 1 to 10. I tried some translators, and I'm getting "scoring", but doesn't sound good to me. Any ideas?

Edit:
The word in Spanish would be "puntuable". I'm designing a database. So that word would be the name of a field in one of my tables.

Comment: As a DBA myself, I would use a field name like `CanBeScored` or `AllowsScoring`. Also, judging from [this](https://www.linguee.com/spanish-english/translation/puntuable.html), it seems like a lot of uses are associated with sports. Is that the context for the program/database that you are developing?

Comment: @mathewb, not actually. The context is a school. I already have a table for grade, meaning the level of knowledge every kid has, for example fourth of fifth grade, that would be a group of kids. And I needed a word for the points? score? grade? that kids get in their assignments.

Comment: By request this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84967/discussion-on-question-by-kenny-barrera-in-one-word-how-can-i-say-that-somethin). (And I messed up and accidentally declined the comment flag - please ignore that @mathewb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, I would say **scorable** is a word.  It may not be in the major dictionaries, but you can often find it in academic literature:

> Using GFP as a **Scorable** Marker in Walnut Somatic Embryo Transformation
>
> Construct Validity of Free-Response and Machine-**Scorable** Forms of a Test
>
> ...the grader may draw up to 21 additional sample units and apply the criteria in the AIM Foreign Material Manual, Table II, (flavor is a non-**scorable** factor).

and so on.

However, if you are talking about something that you can score yourself (or which can score itself), then use *self-scoring* (or *self-rating*) instead of *self-scorable*.

(Edit) "Scorable" is fine for a database column, since those don't have to be perfect English anyway.  Any who reads it will know what it means.

Comment: Is this something a native english speaker would understand without explantion? I think yes, but just asking what do you think.

Comment: @KennyBarrera  I was surprised to find it's not in the dictionary, as it seems perfectly normal to me.  But it might depend on your target audience.

Comment: +1 **scorable** would be  decent name for a boolean column.

Answer (score 3):

What about **Rateable**?

> capable  of  being  rated or  appraised.

[Source: Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/rateable)

Comment: It's worth noting that this word can mean something else (i.e., "liable to taxation"), and that some dictionaries don't even include this definition (see, e.g., [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/rateable), [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/ratable), [YD](http://www.yourdictionary.com/rateable), and [Wordnet 3.0](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=rateable)).